# Deploying to heroku: Invalid end points

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku

I am deploying my app to heroku , i followed all steps as they instruct in their doc for deployment, when I run the app I get the following error in browser:

```
Invalid End point
```

Here is my server

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = require('./app/config/database');

// Connect To Database
mongoose.connect(db.database);

// On Connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('Connected to database '+db.database);
});

// On Error
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Database error: '+err);
});

const app = express();

const movies = require('./app/routes/movies');

// Port Number
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'movies-client')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/movies', movies);

// Index Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Invalid Endpoint');
});

// Start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});
```

Here is my service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Jsonp } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MoviesService {
  queryUrl = '/search/';
  // private apiUrl = '/movies';
  constructor(private http: Http, private _jsonp: Jsonp) { }
  getMovies(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('movies/movies')
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.handleData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  getMovie(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('movies/movies' + id)
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.handleData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  addReview(author, description) {
    const uri = 'movies/comments';
    const obj = {
      author: author,
      description: description
    };
    this
      .http
      .post(uri, obj)
      .subscribe(res =>
          console.log('Done'));
  }
  getReview(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('movies/movies' + id)
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.handleData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  searchMovies(searchStr: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('movies/search' + this.queryUrl + searchStr)
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.handleData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  getInTheaters(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('movies/theatre')
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.handleData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  createMovie(movie: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.post('movies/movies', movie)
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.handleData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private handleData(res: any) {
    const body = res.json();
    console.log(body); // for development purposes only
    return body.result || body || {};
  }
  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for development purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

Here is my private api url:

```
 private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/movies';
```

Example: if I run `http://localhost:8000/movies/movies`
I get all movies , just for reference:

what is wrong with my end points in my code?  what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Hii add this to your server code to this:

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/movies-client/dist/movies-client')));

    app.use('/movies', movies);
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('invaild endpoint');
    });

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/movies-client/dist/movies-client/index.html'));
    });
```